# Backbone.js view render error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, viewrendering

If I do this  - every thing works great -

```
var UserList = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.page',
        render: function(){

            var users = new Users();
            users.fetch({
                success: function() {
                    console.log('success');

                }
            })
                this.$el.html('test');

        }
    });
```

But when I insert the `this.$el.html('test');` into the success callback I am getting an error :

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.$el.html')

```
var UserList = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.page',
        render: function(){

            var users = new Users();
            users.fetch({
                success: function() {
                    console.log('success');
                    this.$el.html('test');
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

The console log is fired correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `success` the context has changed, so `this` no longer refers to the view object (it actually refers to the JQuery Ajax object, I believe).  To work around this you can save a reference to the view using `var self = this`:

```
var users = new Users();
var self = this;
users.fetch({
    success: function() {
        console.log('success');
        self.$el.html('test');
    }
})
```